# Prove that the curvature of $\gamma$ is $\frac{\kappa_{\alpha}}{\sin^2\theta}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves

> Let $\alpha:I\to {\mathbb R}^3$ be a cylindrical helix with a unit vector $u$ such that $u\cdot T_{\alpha}$ is a constant for all $t\in I$. For $t_0\in I$, the curve $$\gamma(t)=\alpha(t)-((\alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0))\cdot u)u$$ is called a *cross-sectional curve*  of the cyliner on which $\alpha$ lies. Prove that the curvature of $\gamma$ is $\frac{\kappa_{\alpha}}{sin^2\theta}$, where $\kappa_{\alpha}$ is the curvature of $\alpha$, and $\theta$ is the angle between $T_{\alpha}$ and $u$

I've proved that:

$$\sin\theta=\frac{\kappa_{\alpha}}{\sqrt{{\kappa_{\alpha}}^2+\tau_{\alpha}^2}}$$

so we're trying to show that:

$$\kappa_{\gamma}=\kappa_{\alpha}+\frac{\tau_{\alpha}^2}{\kappa_{\alpha}}$$

Expressing both sides in terms of their derivatives, we have:

$$\frac{|\gamma'\times\gamma''|}{|\gamma'|^3}=\frac{|\alpha'\times\alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}+\frac{|\alpha'|^3}{|\alpha'\times\alpha''|}\frac{((\alpha'\times\alpha")\cdot{\alpha'''})^2}{|\alpha'\times\alpha"|^4}$$.

Since $\gamma'=\alpha'-(\alpha'\cdot u)u$ and $\gamma''=\alpha''-(\alpha''\cdot u)u$, we get:

$$\frac{|(\alpha'-(\alpha'\cdot u)u)\times{\alpha''}-(\alpha''\cdot u)\alpha'\times u|}{|\alpha'-(\alpha'\cdot u)u|^3}=\frac{|\alpha'\times\alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}+\frac{|\alpha'|^3}{|\alpha'\times\alpha''|}\frac{((\alpha'\times\alpha")\cdot{\alpha'''})^2}{|\alpha'\times\alpha"|^4}$$

Because of the complexity of the equation, I think I should approach to it at some other perspective. I also believe that the conclusion $\sin \theta=\frac{\kappa_{\alpha}}{\sqrt{{\kappa_{\alpha}}^2+\tau_{\alpha}^2}}$ should still be utilized. I hope someone could give me a clue.

Comment: Just want to confirm that t is NOT a arc-length parameter?

Comment: If it is arc-length parameter, the curvature is just $|\alpha''|$ and $\theta$ is constant.

Comment: @XipanXiao The fact that $\theta$ is constant is not implied by assuming that $t$ is an arc length parameter, instead, this is implied by the fact that $\alpha$ is a cylindrical helix. Also why is the curvature just $|\alpha''|$ when assuming that $t$ is an arc length paramenter? I tried and get $|\alpha''-(\alpha''\cdot u)u|$

Comment: $const=u\cdot \alpha'=1\cdot 1\cdot \cos\theta=\cos\theta$ and $k_\alpha=|\alpha''|$

Comment: And you need to state it explicitly in your post whether t is an arc-length parameter or not. It makes much difference.

Comment: You're making life way too complicated when you bring in the torsion of $\alpha$. Don't do that! Remember that $\gamma$ will be a plane curve. I would suggest you determine the speed of $\gamma$ and see that the principal normal of $\gamma$ and that of $\alpha$ agree.

Comment: @XipanXiao: Arclength parametrization is not required for anything in the statement of the OP. It is, however, convenient to *assume* arclength parametrization of $\alpha$ to do the calculations, remembering that $\gamma$ will therefore *not* be unit speed.

Comment: @TedShifrin: After reading your comments I read the OP again and found that $u$ is a const unit vector, which I thought is a vector field before.

Comment: @XipanXiao Sorry, my bad. It's not arc length parameter.

Comment: @TedShifrin No we must consider torsion because a curve is a cylindrical helix iff $\frac {\kappa}{\tau}$ is a constant.

Comment: You don't need that. All you need to use is $T_\alpha\cdot u=\text{constant}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin $T_{\alpha}\cdot u=constant$*

Comment: Yes, sorry! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If t is an arc-length parameter, $\gamma'=\alpha'-(\alpha'\cdot u)u=\alpha'-cu$ where $c=\alpha'\cdot u=\cos\theta$ is constant as assumed. So $\gamma''=\alpha''$ and $|\gamma'|^2=|\alpha'|^2+c^2-2c|\alpha'|\cos\theta=|\alpha'|^2-c^2=1-\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta$
So let $\beta(s)=\gamma(s/\sin\theta)$, $s$ is an arc-length parameter and the curvature is $|\beta''|=|\gamma''/\sin^2\theta|=|\alpha''/\sin^2\theta|=k_\alpha/\sin^2\theta$

Comment: My bad, it's not an arc length parameter. My English's not good enough :)

Comment: By the way, do you know that a curve is called a cylindrical curve if an only if $\frac{\kappa}{\tau}$ is a constant, which in this case equals to $tan\theta$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: got it. Didn't know there are so many types of helixes.